# Consulta sql con filtro dependiendo de dos valores dentro de tablas separadas

Tags: php, sql

Buenas, tengo el siguiente problema quiero hacer como un filtro con sql que muestre solo las filas que tenga por ejemplo en la columna fecha_tarea el valor 21/02/2017 y en la columna estado_tarea el valor 1 este es mi codigo, los dos estan dentro de la tabla tareas_diez

```
 public function mostrar_tarea($datos) {
    $fecha = 21/02/2017;
    $estado = 1;
    $sql = "la consulta con las variables";
    $rs = $this->consulta($sql);
    $registros = "";

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {


        $registros .=  ' <li><a href="#">1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</a></li>';

    }
    if ($registros == "") {
        $registros = '<tr>';
        $registros .= '<td colspan="5">';
        $registros .= 'No existen registros ...';
        $registros .= '</td>';
        $registros .= '</tr>';
    }

    $arr = array('registros' => $registros);
    return ($arr);
}
```

espero entiendan y puedan ayudarme

Comment: Tu pregunta esta confusa, ¿Te arroga algún error?

Comment: la consulta sql es lo que me falta solo necesito que filtre con los valores que capturan el las variables $fecha, $estado

Comment: Son tablas diferentes

Comment: perdon son columnas diferentes dentro de una tabla que se llama tareas_diez las columnas son fecha_tarea y estado

Comment: si tienes problemas con el sql que necesitas, vamos a necesitar ver tu modelo de tablas y los querys que intentaste y porque los mismos no funcionaron. mira [ask] si no lo hiciste todavia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La fecha tendria que ser entre comillas y en el mismo formato que en el motor de base de datos te dejo un ejemplo de como seria

`$fecha = "2017/02/21";
    $estado = 1;
    $sql = "select * from nombre_tabla where fecha_tarea = '$fecha' and estado=$estado";`

Espero que te ayude
Pd: perdon si hay algun error estoy en el celu